# JSTL html select and options: cannot find bean under name

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, javabeans

I have a collection of these objects:

```
public class MyForm
{
    private List<Selection> selections = new ArrayList<Selection>();

    ... getters / setters ...
}

public class Selection
{
    private Option option;
    private List<Option> options = new ArrayList<Option>();

    ... getters /setters ...
}

public class Option
{
    private Integer id;      
    private Integer aValue;
    private Integer anotherValue;
    private Integer choiceIdentifier;

    ... getters /setters ...
}
```

In my JSP I do this:

```
<c:forEach var="selection" items="${selections}">

    ... numerous uses of selection that work fine ...

    <html:select name="selection" property="option" 
        indexed="true" styleId="option_${selection.option.id}"
        title="Option" styleClass="reasonsel" 
        disabled="false" >
        <html:options collection="${selection.options}" property="choiceIdentifier" labelProperty="description"/>
    </html:select>
</c:forEach>
```

And I'm getting:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean under name [Option[id=null, aValue=5678, anotherValue=1234, choiceIdentifier=1212]]
```

Sorry for asking so many questions

Edit:  Updated with the Option bean
Edit:  Updated with the form bean

Comment: I think the problem is property="option". Can you please add form bean class for that JSP file.

Comment: @SivaKumar K, updated.

Comment: Can pl add form bean class to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

`MyForm` is bean for your jsp.

So all the html tag `property` in JSP page should be in your form.

```
<html:select name="selection" property="option"
```

but option is not there in your form page.

Comment: @Lurk21 But that is different. Property is the field , that is used to retrieve the value from form after submitting it. But options are form request values. property is used after submitting the form. It should define in your form.

Comment: I see.  But I will have a lot of these select boxes.  An option for each selection.  That sounds backwards, but it's correct.  The form has an array of selections.  How can I store the option for each selection?

Comment: @Lurk21 you have been given all selection box property name in form class as a separate field.

Comment: Huh?  I didn't get that.  Separately I tried this:  property="${cropSelection.election}" and got "Invalid indexed property"